# Remove layout screen padding

Tags: android

How do I can remove layout padding as shown on screenshot

[image]

Comment: Show your layout file

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RmnGUgB4

Comment: paste your xml file here so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have required reputation points to comment on your question which so I answered your question.

By **removing padding from your parent relative layout** will solve your problem.